# Logistic regression with pandas and sklearn: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I want to run the following model (logistic regression) for the pandas data frame I read.

However, when the predict method comes, it says: "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"

My code is: (Note that there must exist 10 numerical and 4 categorial variables)

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/heart/heart.dat"

s = requests.get(url).content
s = s.decode('utf-8')
s_rows = s.split('\n')
s_rows_cols = [each.split() for each in s_rows]
header_row = ['age','sex','chestpain','restBP','chol','sugar','ecg','maxhr','angina','dep','exercise','fluor','thal','diagnosis']
heart = pd.DataFrame(s_rows_cols, columns = header_row, index=range(271))

pd.to_numeric(heart['age'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['restBP'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['chol'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['sugar'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['maxhr'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['angina'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['dep'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['fluor'])
heart['chestpain'] = heart['chestpain'].astype('category')
heart['ecg'] = heart['ecg'].astype('category')
heart['thal'] = heart['thal'].astype('category')
heart['exercise'] = heart['exercise'].astype('category')

x = pd.to_numeric(heart['diagnosis'])
heart['diagnosis'] = (x > 1).astype(int)

heart_train, heart_test, goal_train, goal_test = train_test_split(heart.loc[:,'age':'thal'], heart.loc[:,'diagnosis'], test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(heart_train, goal_train)
heart_test_results = clf.predict(heart_test)  #From here it is broken 

print(clf.get_params(clf))
print(clf.score(heart_train,goal_train))
```

The data frame info is as follows (print(heart.info()):

```
RangeIndex: 271 entries, 0 to 270
Data columns (total 14 columns):
age          270 non-null object
sex          270 non-null object
chestpain    270 non-null category
restBP       270 non-null object
chol         270 non-null object
sugar        270 non-null object
ecg          270 non-null category
maxhr        270 non-null object
angina       270 non-null object
dep          270 non-null object
exercise     270 non-null category
fluor        270 non-null object
thal         270 non-null category
diagnosis    271 non-null int32
dtypes: category(4), int32(1), object(9)
memory usage: 21.4+ KB
None
```

Do anyone know what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues the reason for this error is how you parse this data:

```
In [116]: %paste
s = requests.get(url).content
s = s.decode('utf-8')
s_rows = s.split('\n')
s_rows_cols = [each.split() for each in s_rows]
header_row = ['age','sex','chestpain','restBP','chol','sugar','ecg','maxhr','angina','dep','exercise','fluor','thal','diagnosis']
heart = pd.DataFrame(s_rows_cols, columns = header_row, index=range(271))

pd.to_numeric(heart['age'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['restBP'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['chol'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['sugar'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['maxhr'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['angina'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['dep'])
pd.to_numeric(heart['fluor'])
heart['chestpain'] = heart['chestpain'].astype('category')
heart['ecg'] = heart['ecg'].astype('category')
heart['thal'] = heart['thal'].astype('category')
heart['exercise'] = heart['exercise'].astype('category')
## -- End pasted text --

In [117]: heart
Out[117]:
      age   sex chestpain restBP   chol sugar  ecg  maxhr angina   dep exercise fluor thal diagnosis
0    70.0   1.0       4.0  130.0  322.0   0.0  2.0  109.0    0.0   2.4      2.0   3.0  3.0         2
1    67.0   0.0       3.0  115.0  564.0   0.0  2.0  160.0    0.0   1.6      2.0   0.0  7.0         1
2    57.0   1.0       2.0  124.0  261.0   0.0  0.0  141.0    0.0   0.3      1.0   0.0  7.0         2
3    64.0   1.0       4.0  128.0  263.0   0.0  0.0  105.0    1.0   0.2      2.0   1.0  7.0         1
4    74.0   0.0       2.0  120.0  269.0   0.0  2.0  121.0    1.0   0.2      1.0   1.0  3.0         1
5    65.0   1.0       4.0  120.0  177.0   0.0  0.0  140.0    0.0   0.4      1.0   0.0  7.0         1
6    56.0   1.0       3.0  130.0  256.0   1.0  2.0  142.0    1.0   0.6      2.0   1.0  6.0         2
7    59.0   1.0       4.0  110.0  239.0   0.0  2.0  142.0    1.0   1.2      2.0   1.0  7.0         2
8    60.0   1.0       4.0  140.0  293.0   0.0  2.0  170.0    0.0   1.2      2.0   2.0  7.0         2
9    63.0   0.0       4.0  150.0  407.0   0.0  2.0  154.0    0.0   4.0      2.0   3.0  7.0         2
..    ...   ...       ...    ...    ...   ...  ...    ...    ...   ...      ...   ...  ...       ...
261  60.0   1.0       4.0  130.0  206.0   0.0  2.0  132.0    1.0   2.4      2.0   2.0  7.0         2
262  58.0   1.0       2.0  120.0  284.0   0.0  2.0  160.0    0.0   1.8      2.0   0.0  3.0         2
263  49.0   1.0       2.0  130.0  266.0   0.0  0.0  171.0    0.0   0.6      1.0   0.0  3.0         1
264  48.0   1.0       2.0  110.0  229.0   0.0  0.0  168.0    0.0   1.0      3.0   0.0  7.0         2
265  52.0   1.0       3.0  172.0  199.0   1.0  0.0  162.0    0.0   0.5      1.0   0.0  7.0         1
266  44.0   1.0       2.0  120.0  263.0   0.0  0.0  173.0    0.0   0.0      1.0   0.0  7.0         1
267  56.0   0.0       2.0  140.0  294.0   0.0  2.0  153.0    0.0   1.3      2.0   0.0  3.0         1
268  57.0   1.0       4.0  140.0  192.0   0.0  0.0  148.0    0.0   0.4      2.0   0.0  6.0         1
269  67.0   1.0       4.0  160.0  286.0   0.0  2.0  108.0    1.0   1.5      2.0   3.0  3.0         2
270  None  None       NaN   None   None  None  NaN   None   None  None      NaN  None  NaN      None

[271 rows x 14 columns]
```

NOTE: pay attention at the very last row with NaN's

try to do it this simplified way instead:

```
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/heart/heart.dat"

header_row = ['age','sex','chestpain','restBP','chol','sugar','ecg','maxhr','angina','dep','exercise','fluor','thal','diagnosis']

In [118]: df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', header=None, names=header_row)

In [119]: df
Out[119]:
      age  sex  chestpain  restBP   chol  sugar  ecg  maxhr  angina  dep  exercise  fluor  thal  diagnosis
0    70.0  1.0        4.0   130.0  322.0    0.0  2.0  109.0     0.0  2.4       2.0    3.0   3.0          2
1    67.0  0.0        3.0   115.0  564.0    0.0  2.0  160.0     0.0  1.6       2.0    0.0   7.0          1
2    57.0  1.0        2.0   124.0  261.0    0.0  0.0  141.0     0.0  0.3       1.0    0.0   7.0          2
3    64.0  1.0        4.0   128.0  263.0    0.0  0.0  105.0     1.0  0.2       2.0    1.0   7.0          1
4    74.0  0.0        2.0   120.0  269.0    0.0  2.0  121.0     1.0  0.2       1.0    1.0   3.0          1
5    65.0  1.0        4.0   120.0  177.0    0.0  0.0  140.0     0.0  0.4       1.0    0.0   7.0          1
6    56.0  1.0        3.0   130.0  256.0    1.0  2.0  142.0     1.0  0.6       2.0    1.0   6.0          2
7    59.0  1.0        4.0   110.0  239.0    0.0  2.0  142.0     1.0  1.2       2.0    1.0   7.0          2
8    60.0  1.0        4.0   140.0  293.0    0.0  2.0  170.0     0.0  1.2       2.0    2.0   7.0          2
9    63.0  0.0        4.0   150.0  407.0    0.0  2.0  154.0     0.0  4.0       2.0    3.0   7.0          2
..    ...  ...        ...     ...    ...    ...  ...    ...     ...  ...       ...    ...   ...        ...
260  58.0  0.0        3.0   120.0  340.0    0.0  0.0  172.0     0.0  0.0       1.0    0.0   3.0          1
261  60.0  1.0        4.0   130.0  206.0    0.0  2.0  132.0     1.0  2.4       2.0    2.0   7.0          2
262  58.0  1.0        2.0   120.0  284.0    0.0  2.0  160.0     0.0  1.8       2.0    0.0   3.0          2
263  49.0  1.0        2.0   130.0  266.0    0.0  0.0  171.0     0.0  0.6       1.0    0.0   3.0          1
264  48.0  1.0        2.0   110.0  229.0    0.0  0.0  168.0     0.0  1.0       3.0    0.0   7.0          2
265  52.0  1.0        3.0   172.0  199.0    1.0  0.0  162.0     0.0  0.5       1.0    0.0   7.0          1
266  44.0  1.0        2.0   120.0  263.0    0.0  0.0  173.0     0.0  0.0       1.0    0.0   7.0          1
267  56.0  0.0        2.0   140.0  294.0    0.0  2.0  153.0     0.0  1.3       2.0    0.0   3.0          1
268  57.0  1.0        4.0   140.0  192.0    0.0  0.0  148.0     0.0  0.4       2.0    0.0   6.0          1
269  67.0  1.0        4.0   160.0  286.0    0.0  2.0  108.0     1.0  1.5       2.0    3.0   3.0          2

[270 rows x 14 columns]
```

also pay attention at automatically parsed (guessed) dtypes - `pd.read_csv()` will do all necesarry convertions for you:

```
In [120]: df.dtypes
Out[120]:
age          float64
sex          float64
chestpain    float64
restBP       float64
chol         float64
sugar        float64
ecg          float64
maxhr        float64
angina       float64
dep          float64
exercise     float64
fluor        float64
thal         float64
diagnosis      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it was the train_test_split thing.

I would suggest turning your X, and y into numpy arrays to avoid this problem. This usually solves for this.

```
X = heart.loc[:,'age':'thal'].as_matrix()
y = heart.loc[:,'diagnosis'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size, random_state)
```

and then fit for 
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)